# How do I get the value from a select2 dropdown?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-select2

Ok, I load some data (JSON), then via select menu I generate a new select menu based on the value chosen: in other words, select a county, generate a another select with all the towns in that county and at the same time apply the select2 plugin so it's searchable.

I need to be able to put the selected down into a hidden field for submission and this is where I'm getting stuck. Can anybody help me please, thanks. JQuery is not my strongest.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    //var county = $('#county').find(":selected").text();
    $('select').on('change', function() {
    var countySelect = $(this).val();
    console.log(countySelect);
    $.getJSON('irishtowns.json', function(data) {
    var output="<select id='townSelect'>";
    output+="<option>Choose a town</option>";
    for (var i in data.irishtowns) {
        if (data.irishtowns[i].county == countySelect) {
        output+="<option value='>" + data.irishtowns[i].town + "'>" + data.irishtowns[i].town + "</option>";
        }
    }
    output+="</select>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    $('#placeholder select').select2();

    });

  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: there is a syntax error in binding the data to output `output+="<option value='" + data.irishtowns[i].town + "'>" + data.irishtowns[i].town + "</option>";` use this one line.

Answer (score 3):

In the change event, you can access the `select` which triggered the change event with `this`. To use jQuery functions and get the value, you should do this (which you already did for the first select):

```
var selected = $(this).val();
```

Since you created a new select each time, you must recreate a change handler:

```
$('#placeholder select').on('change', function() {
    $('#hidden').val($(this).val());
})
```

Some optimizations could be used:

- You are mixing traditional JavaScript and jQuery (which works fine and is understandable if you are beginning, but make things harder to read).
- You should use IDs for the change handler to make sure this applies only to the select you want.
- Maybe recreating a select is not necessary. Only update the options.
- (I do not know select2, so maybe this is not optimal yet).

Here are some suggestions:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Make townSelect a select2 and update the value in hidden when changed
    $('#townSelect').select2();
    $('#townSelect').on('change', function() {
        var selectedTown = $(this).val();
        $('#hidden').val(selectedTown);
    });

    // Change the available towns when county changes
    $('#county').on('change', function() {
        var countySelect = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON('irishtowns.json', function(data) {
            // Remove previous options
            var select = $('#townSelect').empty();
            // Add new options
            // & trigger 'change' to make select2 aware of it
            select.append($('<option>', { text: 'Choose a town' }).change();
            for (var i in data.irishtowns) {
                if (data.irishtowns[i].county == countySelect) {
                    select.append($('<option>', { value: data.irishtowns[i].town, text: data.irishtowns[i].town });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<!-- ... -->
<select id="county"><!--...--></select>
<select id="townSelect"><option>Choose a county</option></select>
```

Comment: Might have to re-trigger the `change` event on `#townSelect` after adding the first placeholder option, but past that your answer looks correct.

Comment: @KevinBrown Do you advise triggering the `change` in order to keep the hidden field up-to-date? If so, just confirm and I will edit the answer. If not, could you explain the reason and I will edit the answer all the same. Thanks!

Comment: Not to keep the hidden field up-to-date, but to notify Select2 itself that the state has changed (specifically, to show the placeholder instead of existing selections). But there is the nice side effect of updating the hidden field, I guess.

Comment: The additional on-change event doesn't appear to work

Comment: Huh. I did not try it since I do not know select2. Maybe using `on` after having made the `select2` is a problem. I edited my answer to separate the select2 and change handler binding. Is it better?

Comment: @Chris Digging up an oldie. Since this answer seems to have solved your problem, maybe you could accept it, so that this question does not remain "unresolved"?

Answer (score 0):

You got syntax error in your value attribute.

Try:

```
    output+="<option value='"  + data.irishtowns[i].town + "'>" + data.irishtowns[i].town + "</option>";
```

Comment: This does not answer the question and would rather have been welcome as a comment.